# How to draw errorbar on one series out of several of a bar graph

Tags: matlab, errorbar

I am not familiar with `errorbar` function in Matlab. The bar graph I am drawing has two series. I just need to plot the error bar for one of them. How should I plot this? Thank you! The error data for series 1 is defined in `error_1` variable.

```
series_1 = [ 10 20 30 40 50];
series_2 = [2 4 6 8 10];
error_1 = [0.5 1.0 1.5 2.0 2.5];
a = [series_1' zeros(length(series_1),1)];
b = [zeros(length(series_1),1) series_2'];
figure(1);
[AX,H1,H2] = plotyy(1:length(series_1),a,1:length(series_2),b,'bar','bar');
```

[image]

Comment: I reccomend http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10803-barweb--bargraph-with-error-bars- for the error bars. I think to skip plotting the error bars, you can just set them to zero.

Comment: Almost forgot, if the code doesn't work for you, check the comment section of that page. Someone has posted changes that will 'fix' the code to work with the newer versions of MATLAB.

Comment: Thank you! Does this one support two y-axis cases? The two series of my data are of different scales so I have to use two y axises.

Comment: Hm, perhaps not, but this might facilitate that: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10839-bartwoyaxis